# "Extra argument in call" i am having this error .... what is wrong with this code

Tags: ios, database, swift2

What is wrong with this code?  I am trying to retrieve data from my SQL database.

```
import Foundation

class Service {
    var settings:Settings!

    init(){
        self.settings = Settings()
    }

    func getContacts (callback:(NSDictionary)-> ()){
        request(settings.viewContacts, callback: callback)
    }

    func request(url: String , callback:(NSDictionary) ->()) {
        let nsURL = NSURL(string : url)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(nsURL!){
            (data , reponse , error) in
            let error: NSError?

            var reponse = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error) as NSDictionary // extra argument in call , i am having this error.
            callback(reponse)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually `Swift2` has no `NSError` on `NSJSONSerialization`

You need to wrap it in a `do/catch` block as this is the preferred way of reporting errors, rather than using `NSError`:

```
do {
   let reponse = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary
   // use reponse
    callback(reponse)
} catch {
    // report error
}
```

if you need the `NSError` object properties,use:

```
do {
    let reponse = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary

    // use reponse
    callback(reponse)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("json error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: thanks brother i was trying this from last few days n you solved it :)

Comment: @ZainHabib -- have a nice day my bro, actually swift 2.0 is readuced the code format,

Comment: brother i want to make an app which will retrieve contacts from database , so can you give me any hint how can i categories those contacts ?e.g all schools numbers , hospitals numbers  , hotels etc ... do i have to make different tables in data base or there is some other way in swift ?